# Find all $n$th root of $z$ for $z=4\sqrt{2} +4\sqrt{2}i$ and $n=3$. Plot the roots in the complex plane.

Tags: trigonometry

Find all $n$th root of $z$ for $z=4\sqrt{2} +4\sqrt{2}i$ and $n=3$. Plot the roots in the complex plane.

I have no idea how to do this, please help out.

Comment: start by writing $z$ in the polar form $re^{i\theta} = r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$.

Comment: Is plotting them necessary?

Comment: I don't know what polar form is..

Comment: @happyglad Then you should definitely learn it.

Comment: Yeah, he wants up to plot them, i've been trying to google, but haven't had any luck finding anything.

Comment: There's [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form).

Comment: Would it help to observe that $z=8\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i\right)$?

Comment: Learn what polar form is. This is clearly a homework assignment, so you should have that in your notes and textbook. You have been taught how to find the $p$th roots of arbitrary $z = re^{i\theta}\in \mathbb{C}$; this shouldn't be a new problem or something you have no idea about.

Comment: This wasn't taught and is on the final exam study guide. I have an hour to learn this.

Comment: This is the post I have seen from you today on this subject.  It sounds like there is a hole in your study materials on the polar form of complex numbers and DeMoivre's theorem.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints.

1. Plot your complex number in the complex plane.  (Just mark off $4\sqrt{2}$ on the real axis and the imaginary axis; no need to compute $4\sqrt{2}$.)
2. Draw an arrow from the origin to your point.
3. Calculate how long this line segment is.  You can use the Pythagorean theorem.  This is $r$ in polar form.
4. What angle does this line segment make with the positive real axis, going counterclockwise?  This is $\theta$.
5. From there, you can use de Moivre's theorem to calculate the roots.

Can you give it a shot?

Answer (score 0):

Without the polar form, you can do it the hard way:
$$
(x+yi)^3=4\sqrt{2}+4\sqrt{2}\,i
$$
becomes
$$
(x^3-3xy^2)+(3x^2y-y^3)i=4\sqrt{2}+4\sqrt{2}\,i
$$
Let's try removing $\sqrt{2}$, by choosing $x=X\sqrt{2}$ and $y=Y\sqrt{2}$, getting
$$
(X^3-3XY^2)+(3X^2Y-Y^3)=2+2i
$$
In particular,
$$
X^3-3XY^2=3X^2Y-Y^3
$$
that becomes
$$
X^3+Y^3-3XY^2-3X^2Y=0
$$
or
$$
(X+Y)(X^2-XY+Y^2)-3XY(X+Y)=0
$$
or, finally,
$$
(X+Y)(X^2-4XY+Y^2)=0
$$
This, together with $X^3-3XY^2=2$, will give you the solutions.

For instance, the case $Y=-X$ gives $X^3-3X^3=2$, so $X=-1$ and $Y=1$.

Solve the case
\begin{cases}
X^2-4XY+Y^2=0
\\[4px]
X^3-3XY^2=2
\end{cases}
by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

More explicitly,
if
$z=4\sqrt{2} +4\sqrt{2}i
$,
$|z|
=\sqrt{2(4\sqrt{2})^2}
=\sqrt{2(32)}
=8
$,
so
$z
=8\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)
$.

Noting that
$\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)
=e^{\pi i /4}
$,
$z
=8e^{\pi i /4}
$,
so that
$w
=z^{1/3}
=2e^{\pi i /12}
$
is the principal cube root
and the others are
$we^{2\pi i/3}
$
and
$we^{4\pi i/3}
$.